# Generic Type Exceptions

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

Recently I came across the problem of creating an exception with a given message from within a generic method. For instance, the following code works as expected:

```
public static void Throw<T>() where T : Exception, new()
{
    throw new T();
}

...

public static void Main()
{
    Throw<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(); // Throws desired exception but with a generic message.
}
```

However, I would like to be able to write

```
public static void Throw<T>(string message) where T : Exception, new()
{
    T newException = new T();

    newException.Message = message; // Not allowed. 'Message' is read-only.

    throw newException;
}

...

public static void Main()
{
    Throw<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>("You must specify a non-negative integer."); // Throws desired exception.
}
```

Is there any way of achieving this without the use of reflection either to change the value of the `Message` property or dinamically activate an instance of the type with the desired parameters?

Comment: Nice observation @Oded at first i missed it :)

Comment: @Oded and zenwalker: will that even compile? Don't think so...

Comment: No. It won't compile. It only accepts a parameterless constructor as enforced by the `new()` constraint.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write:  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Custom message here")?  What advantage does this method have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), "MyException description")` to enable a custom message.

There is no way to create the instance without the use of the reflection or the use of the activator.

#### See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The new constraint is only valid for default (parameterless) constructors, try this instead:

```
public static void Throw<T>(string message) where T : Exception
{
    System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    T newException = (T)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { message });

    throw newException;
}
```

(note that you don't need the new constraint in this case)